# Where is Content Type View Access stored in the Database?

Tags: nodes, users

I am looking for where Per Content Type - View Access is stored in the database.

Out of the box, I understand that Drupal can limit certain roles to be able to Edit/Delete All/Own Nodes but not access to View Nodes of certain types. I found those stored in the `role_permissions` table.

I use the [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) and the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access/) module and have found the "per-node" permissions in the ACL tables of the database.

I have limited View Access on specific Content Types to specific Roles, but cannot find where in the database this information is stored.

Where can I find that?

The reason I want to know is I want my custom module I am working on to work with the Content Access module to be able to grant/revoke access on certain Content Types to certain Roles.